# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'products.all_category' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `all_countries`)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
    'mysql2' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

products is the default database and all_category is the table name in second database called category it is not even identifying the second database category ,it is only taking the first default one while configuring ,here is the query inside controller:-

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql2')->table("all_category")->get();
```

Any help would be much appreciate, Thanks in advance

Comment: try this commands : `php artisan config:clear` 
`php artisan cache:clear` 
`composer dump-autoload` !

Comment: thank you so much @ Maraboc ,it worked

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @Maraboc perhaps your comments should have been an answer instead of comment.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin done ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this artisan commands to clear the config cache :

```
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan cache:clear 
composer dump-autoload
```